# Use D3.js to visualize neo4j graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, visualization

I have neo4j database, which I have already exported in json format. I am trying to visualize it usign d3.js. I want to use http://bl.ocks.org/paulovn/9686202 template. So, I picked three codes: `index.html`, `movie-network.css` and `movie-network.js` and put them in one folder. In the same folder I have kept the `result.json` which is the whole graph of neo4j. To use the template I changed the file path accordingly as:

```
d3.json(
    'result.json', // THIS EARLIER WAS 'movie-network-25-7-3.json'
    function(data) {
```

But opening the index.html in a browser gives blank page and no viualization of graph happens.

Comment: Have you opened up Chrome's or Firefox's dev tool console to check if there are any errors?

Comment: Is your file in the SAME exact format as the previous one?